# Regex exec() isn't returning first occurrence in string, but returns subsequent matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all occurrences of colors in a string. If I have a string of 'red #fff green #000000' it will only match the second result, so green and #000000 in this case.

```
// csscolor is just json of all color names

const types = {
  hsl: new RegExp(/(hsla?\(\s*(\d{1,3})\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*,\s*(\d{1,3}\%)\s*(?:\s*,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*)?\))/gi),
  rgb: new RegExp(/(rgb\((\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}),\s*(\d{1,3}))\)/gi),
  hex: new RegExp(/(#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3})/gi),
  keyword: new RegExp('\\b(' + Object.keys(csscolors).join('|') + ')\\b', 'gi')
};

const execRegex = (re, str) => {
  var match;
  while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log('regexp.lastIndex:', re.lastIndex, 
                'index:', match.index,
                'match[0]:', match[0]);
  }
}

const getMatches = (str) => ({
  hsl: types.hsl.test(str) ? execRegex(types.hsl, str) : null,
  rgb: types.rgb.test(str) ? execRegex(types.rgb, str) : null,
  hex: types.hex.test(str) ? execRegex(types.hex, str) : null,
  keyword: types.keyword.test(str) ? execRegex(types.keyword, str) : null
});

getMatches('red #fff green #000000');
```

output, missing red and #fff:

```
regexp.lastIndex: 22 
index: 15 
match[0]: #000000

regexp.lastIndex: 14 
index: 9 
match[0]: green
```

I've tested the regex's with match() and they seem to be working just fine, but match doesn't provide index's for multiple occurrences.

disclaimer: RegExp noob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegExp `test` and `exec` methods both use the RegExp `lastIndex` property, so when you call test, you're advancing past the first match, then finding the second with exec.

See this related Stack Overflow post: [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I fixed it by resetting the lastIndex to 0 in execRegex

Comment: That should do it. A failed test/exec call will also reset things. Best of luck!